# Select a dropdown element previously selected by a user in a Laravel 4 environment

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am looking for a way to select a dropdown element previously selected by a user in a Laravel 4 environment without an if statment on every line.

Dropdown HTML example, from a Blade template:

```
<select id="frequency" name="schedule_data_dropdown">
    <option value="">Choose from dropdown
    <option value="custom">Custom
    <optgroup label="Frequency less then an hour">
    <option value="Every min">Every min
    <option value="Every 5 min">Every 5 min
    <option value="Every 15 min">Every 15 min
    <option value="Every 30 min">Every 30 min
    <option value="Every 45 min">Every 45 min
    <optgroup label="Frequency less then a dag">
    <option value="Every hour">Every hour
    <option value="Every 2 hour">Every 2 hour
    <option value="Every 6 hour">Every 6 hour
    <option value="Every 12 hour">Every 12 hour
    <optgroup label="Frequency less then a week">
    <option value="Every day">Every day
    <option value="Every weekday">Every weekday
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in a blade template then use Laravel's Form class. First set up an array to hold the options:

```
$options = array(
    'Choose from dropdown',
    'custom' => 'Custom',
    'Frequency less than an hour' => array(
        'Every min' => 'Every min',
        'Every 5 min' => 'Every 5 min'
        ...
    ),
    'Frequency less than a day' => array(
        'Every hour' => 'Every hour',
        'Every 2 hour' => 'Every 2 hour',
        ...
    ),
    'Frequency less than a week' => array(
        'Every day' => 'Every day',
        'Every weekday' => 'Every weekday'
    )
);
```

Now create the form Element:

```
{{ Form::select('schedule_data_dropdown', $options, $user_pre_selected, array('id' => 'frequency')) }}
```